# Bootstrap multiple select overriding multiple select2

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, laravel-5.4, bootstrap-select

When i load th page, initially the expanded droplist of multiple select box is showing up, then immediatly changing to multiple select2 (what i need).

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple keywords  form-control"  style="width: 70%" name="keywords[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

how can i override the normal multiple select box.I'am spending too much time on this... 
[image: Initial view]
[image: after a second]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `$(document).ready(function(e){});` from the page. now it is loading correctly.